# python pandas date read_table

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have the following input file:

```
2012,10,3,AAPL,BUY,200
2012,12,5,AAPL,SELL,200
```

How can I read this in into a pandas dataframe wth following columns:

```
index: default int range # 0
column1: datetime(2012,10,3,16) # 2012-10-03 16:00
column2: string # AAPL
column3: string # BUY
column4: integer # 200
```

Example:

```
0 2012-10-03 16:00 AAPL BUY  200
1 2012-12-05 16:00 AAPL SELL 200
```

Tried (pandas 0.7):

```
In[2]: pandas.io.parsers.read_csv("input.csv", parse_dates=[[0,1,2]], header=None)
Out[2]: 
    X.1  X.2  X.3   X.4   X.5  X.6
0  2012   10    3  AAPL   BUY  200
1  2012   12    5  AAPL  SELL  200
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the [read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html#pandas.io.parsers.read_csv) function. Ensure that your csv includes a header or pass `header=None` for correct parsing. `parse_dates=[[0,1,2]]` will facilitate the desired dattime parsing.

```
In [4]: pandas.io.parsers.read_csv("input.csv", parse_dates=[[0,1,2]], header=None)
Out[4]: 
              X0_X1_X2    X3    X4   X5
0  2012-10-03 00:00:00  AAPL   BUY  200
1  2012-12-05 00:00:00  AAPL  SELL  200
```

Comment: That is what I did but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution with pandas read_csv or read_table

Comment: @rdw. What version of python and pandas are you using?

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.7.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/version.pyc

Comment: Is it possible for you to use 0.8.0+? I think that may be required.